# JSON Parsing in Objective-c[xcode 6]

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json, xcode6.1

I am getting the response like this. How can I get the values?
`MODEOFTRAVEL_ID` its the key value and `MODEOFTRAVELNAME` this is the other key.

```
{
        ColumnValuesList =         (
                        (
                1,
                Flight
            ),
                        (
                2,
                Train
            ),
                        (
                3,
                "By Road"
            ),
                        (
                21,
                "By Bus"
            )
        );
        TableColumns =         (
            "MODEOFTRAVEL_ID",
            MODEOFTRAVELNAME
        );
        TableName = "CTZ_MODEOFTRAVEL";
    },
```

Comment: You need to show your code so-far. In the question, how did you produce the output? Do you already have an `NSDictionary` or is this a formatted `NSString`?

Comment: thanks for giving the replay I parse the response and after  iam getting like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question data is the contents of a variable (say d)  which is an `NSDictionary` then:

Example:

```
NSDictionary *d = @{
    @"ColumnValuesList" : @[
        @[ @1,  @"Flight" ],
        @[ @2,  @"Train" ],
        @[ @3,  @"By Road" ],
        @[ @21, @"By Bus" ]
    ],
    @"TableColumns" : @[
        @"MODEOFTRAVEL_ID",
        @"MODEOFTRAVELNAME"
    ],
    @"TableName" : @"CTZ_MODEOFTRAVEL"
    };

NSString *columnName0 = d[@"TableColumns"][0];
NSString *columnName1 = d[@"TableColumns"][1];
NSLog(@"columnName0: %@", columnName0);
NSLog(@"columnName1: %@", columnName1);
```

Output:

> columnName0: MODEOFTRAVEL_ID
>   columnName1: MODEOFTRAVELNAME

Comment: How can i get values by using the  "MODEOFTRAVEL_ID",
           " MODEOFTRAVELNAME"
two key values. this response          (
                1,
                Flight
            ),